# Reading and Writing to Unverified Contract

Tags: solidity

Locked the LP for a token via a locking service. I have the LP in my wallet. The locking service went under and took down their website. Now, I cannot interact with the contract to unlock the LP. Additionally, the locking contract is unverified. I can read some of the functions using an ABI decompiler. But, is there a way to interact with the locking contract to write the function to unlock the LP? The locking contract is on Pulsechain which is a fork of ETH. Any help or guidance is appreciated. https://scan.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/bafybeidn64pd2u525lmoipjl4nh3ooa2imd7huionjsdepdsphl5slfowy/

CA: 0x234e9Ed0048F7Dfbb7D5E01C779F5C2363071C6E